# blanking a field when zero using ng-model, is that possible?

Tags: angularjs

If `vm.agentCommission` is 0 then I want the field to be blank, so the user dont have to remove the zero before typing.

I tried this:

```
 <input ng-model="vm.agentCommission ? '' : vm.agentCommission" ....
```

But I get this:

```
Expression 'vm.agentCommission ? '' : vm.agentCommission' is non-assignable.
```

Is there a way to do this in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the ternary operation inside `ng-change`

```
ng-change="(vm.agentCommission === '0') ? vm.agentCommission = '' : vm.agentCommission"
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 var vm = this;
 //vm.agentCommission = "";

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
<input ng-model="vm.agentCommission" ng-change="(vm.agentCommission === '0') ? vm.agentCommission = '' : vm.agentCommission"> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is the "===" ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Ok thanks. Your solution only works if I set it to "" in the controller and I wanted to avoid doing that. And even if I do that, change it to 1 and then back to 0, it does not blank the field.

Comment: what do u mean? i remove the controller part and it works

Comment: Ahh yes it works when you make changes to the field, you are no longer allowed to type "0"  as the value.  But what about when the field is initialized with a 0 in `vm.agentCommission` - then the zero is still there.  How do I get rid of that?  Is the controller the only way?

Comment: I tried this, it does not change the 0 with blank.  `ng-init="(vm.agentCommission === '0') ? vm.agentCommission = '' : vm.agentCommission"`

Comment: got it...  ` ng-init="(vm.agentCommission == 0) ? vm.agentCommission = '' : vm.agentCommission"` this worked

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ng-model="vm.agentCommission > 0 ? vm.agentCommission  : '' " >
```

I changed your code bit. Kindly check if this works.